# Adding a string to wordpress title not adding to backend

Tags: wordpress

I have been inserting title into the wordpress post title from front end it was not storing the string as it is.

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$new_help = array(
'post_title' => $title,
'post_status'=> 'publish'
);
wp_insert_post();
```

the string i am inserting is <<hello_world>>

It was storing only <<>>

Comment: can you give more details about problem.

Comment: @aviboy2006 The issue was i am <<hello_world>> inserting post in wordpress with title <<hello_world>> but it was not storing as it is it stores only <<>>

Comment: Never store unsanitized data!, always always always do check and sanitize. you can use filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);, or any other filter flag that suits you. In your example you forgot to add $new_help into the wp_insert_post();

Answer (score 2):

I think you just forgot to incorporate the arguments into the wp_insert_post function.

```
if( isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title']) )

{

 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $new_help = array(
  'post_title' => $title,
  'post_status'=> 'publish'
 );

 wp_insert_post($new_help);

}
```